# A good upper bound on the size of k-biclique in random bipartite graphs.

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $G = (X \cup Y, E)$ be a random bipartite graph, where $X$ and $Y$ are the set of vertices and $E$ the set of edges. I want to find an upper bound of the largest biclique in which exactly $k$ vertices of $X$ are part of the biclique. A biclique of $G$ is a set of vertices $X' \subset X$ and $Y' \subset Y$ where there is a edge between each node $x \in X'$ and each node $y \in Y'$.
Could any of you help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: This is very elementary.  Is it homework?

Comment: No. I know some upper bounds.. but i need an algorithm to find a strong one, since i'm using it to write a branch-and-bound algorithm to solve the problem.